# Creating Email Application with Rails and Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm currently trying to create an email application using Rails and Sendgrid. This application should have the basic features of sending emails. Does anyone know how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are constrained to using your own server, I suggest starting with [Heroku's SendGrid Package](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid). It's free and fairly easy to setup and get started. Here's the [Getting Started Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid).

After you setup sendgrid, you use [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) as you normally would.

Comment: The Heroku docs are a solid way to get started.  You could also look at our Rails example http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/rails-example-using-smtp/ too.